# Count number of files in different sub-directory

Tags: python, count, directory, subdirectory, os.walk

I am trying to count total number of images in each sub-directory.
One Main Directory and 300 sub-directories every subdirectory have 1 image but below code is showing different number of images in each directory for almost 20 sub-directories it should be 1 image instead.
**output:**

Images: 0 Directory: 1
Images: 3 Directory: 2
Images: 5 Directory: 3
and so on. but following code doesn't display anything no error nothing.

```
import os
path='C:/Python36/cclabel/n13/'
def count_em(path):
    x = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
       files_count = (len(files))
       x = x + 1
       print("Images:",files_count,"Directory:",x)
    return files_count
```

Comment: above code is from same post but it doesn't display anything also few of other code from post are not traversing in sub-directories.

Comment: Are you _calling_ `count_em` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted does not quite do what you need. However, I have edited it due to my understanding of your question. Hopefully, it is what you need.

```
import os    
path ="C:/Directory/"

def count_em(path):
    x = 0
    files_count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
       files_count += (len(files))
       x = x + 1

       print("Images:",files_count,"Directory:",x)
    return files_count



count_em(path)
```

**Edit:**

Output for a directory that contains 5 directories and sub-directories and files:

```
Images: 0 Directory: 1
Images: 3 Directory: 2
Images: 3 Directory: 3
Images: 5 Directory: 4
Images: 9 Directory: 5
Images: 9 Directory: 6
.
.
.
.
.
Images: 84 Directory: 44
Images: 88 Directory: 45
Images: 90 Directory: 46
Images: 90 Directory: 47
Images: 90 Directory: 48
Images: 94 Directory: 49
```

Comment: I added the output of the script. I do not know why it wouldn't display anything unless there is something wrong with the path chosen.

Comment: Are you sure that you create a call to the function `count_em()`?

Comment: oh yes it worked but my main directory (n13) have one folder while output is Images: 0 Directory: 1
Images: 1 Directory: 2
Total images:  1

Comment: I have edited it so it meets your requirements. Is that correct?

Comment: No but your old code worked thanks now i want to add a simple condition that ` if files_count>2:` remove current folder `shutil.rmtree()` using this but something i wrong

Comment: `shutil.rmtree()`  function will delete the current directory and all files and subdirectories below it.  Are you sure is that what you want?

Comment: No i just want to delete a sub directory which have more than 2 images

Comment: You cannot delete a sub-directory without deleting their sub-directories and files. However, you can add the folders' names which have more than two images into a list and running a loop after your program finishes to delete all intended directories. If I did not quite understand what you have just said, please elaborate.

Comment: my sub directoryy doesnt have any sub directory it just have images

Comment: Yes, use the function you mentioned which is [shutil.rmtree()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree), make sure you pass the full path for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941858/delete-a-current-directory-based-on-if-condition

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Farrell suggested, you need to call the function `count_em`. Writing the function alone does not do it. You have to call it. Stick the following at the end of your file and you are good to go:

```
total = count_em(path)
print('Total images: ', total)
```

Comment: Okay this code returns total number of images in main directory while i want to count total no of images in each sub directory (total 100 sub in main directory) please check expected outcome above