# Delete a current directory based on If condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, subdirectory, shutil

Following code counts number of image in each sub directory. how to delete a sub directory if images in sub-directory are more than 2.
**n13 is main directory**=> which have **300 sub-directories(1...300)**=> each sub-directory have **images**.

**output:**
Images:2, Directory:1
Images:3, Directory:2
Images:4, Directory:3

```
import os
path='C:/n13/'
def count_em(path):
    x = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
       files_count = (len(files))
       x = x + 1
       print("Images:",files_count,"Directory:",x)
    return files_count
```

Comment: if files_count >2 : shutil.rmtree(os.walk(path))

Comment: error "lstat: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not generator
"

Comment: os.walk(path) in this place give subdir path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shutil.rmtree()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to delete a folder with its sub-directories and files.

```
import os
import shutil

path='C:/n13/'

def count_em(path):
    x = 0
    files_count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        files_count = (len(files))
        if files_count >= 2:
            shutil.rmtree(root)
        x = x + 1
        print("Images:", files_count, "Directory:", x)
    return files_count


count_em(path)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47964336/two-pass-connected-component-number-of-components-issue/47964562#47964562  Please check this issue